# Compiling Objective-C Application on Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, macos, gcc, compiler-construction

I've written a command line application in XCode using Objective-C. When added to my `/usr/local/bin` path is works as expected in OS X. However, I would like to make the binary work on Linux.

The binary relies on an Objective-C framework. How would I go about doing this? Or is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org).

Comment: Take also a look at this project : Cocotron [link](http://www.cocotron.org)

Comment: Both of those comments are the correct answers. I believe though, that cocotron's Linux support is limited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible by installing GNUstep: http://www.gnustep.org/

The basics of Objective-C are supported by the GNU compiler collection. In order to utilize the full power of Objective-C together with the Cocoa /openStep environments on Linux, and to work with many of the examples covered in this book, it is necessary to install gcc, the gcc Objective-C support package and the GNUstep environment.

The gcc Objective-C support can be installed on Linux simply by installing the gcc-objc package which is available with all Linux distributions. There are, however, two different paths to installing GNUstep. On those Linux distributions for which pre-built GNUstep packages are provided this is simply a matter of issuing the appropriate command to install GNUstep. On Linux distributions for which pre-built packages are not available, the process involves downloading the GNUstep source code and then building and installing the packages manually.

Take a look at this article explaining this step by (gnu)step :) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_and_Using_GNUstep_and_Objective-C_on_Linux

Comment: The official documentation is available at http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/User_Guides

Comment: Yes sure but the article is really good and helps "step-by-step" to install and work with gnustep

Comment: If your code use Objective-C 2.0 features like ARC, Objective-C literals, block, properties ... you cannot use GCC but you need to install clang and GNUstep Objective-c runtime. If you do not know how to limit yourself to old dialect, it's a very good idea to avoid the article and find another one for clang.

Comment: I'll mark this as the right answer. It didn't work for me because of my unusual circumstances of needing an external framework. But it did work for simpler examples.